# AVPlayer stops playing when user drags within buffered zone

Tags: ios, avplayer

I am using AvPlayer to play a video file.

```
NSString *strURL = @"Some URL";
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
self.p = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:movieURL];
self.controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
self.controller.player = self.p;
[self addChildViewController:self.controller];
[self.view addSubview:self.mp.view];
[self.p play];
```

This adds a default AVPlayerViewController to the AVPlayer.

I notice that if the user drags the seekbar within the bufferred zone.

My video play will instantly stuck. At this no user action can resume the video.

I am playing an HLS file. Do you guys know what might be causing the AVPlayer to stuck?

Comment: stuck forever or until it loads? can you give it time?

Comment: @MohammadBashirSidani It is stuck forever. The spinning icon on the status bar is gone as well.